Folder permission on User folder with VsCode live server
As part of my web application, I am saving files into a server folder previously created. The files are created by node server under this folder and later read by javascript frontend.
This works fine when running locally with Live Server in a MAC, but when I go to windows the files are placed under the User directory and I am getting Error: EACCES: permission denied, stat 'c:\fagce\medpro4\medpro3\data\requests\52d942a5-5bd2-4111-a81f-960fda26682f.pdf' when trying to read it from the front end.
I think I gave the proper permissions for testing purposes:
enter image description here
How do I fix this so my front end can read the file properly when running Live Server in Windows?
Thanks!!
